# React rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, state

I have component

```
const ComponentA: React.FC<ComponentAProps> = (props) => {

const [invalidFields, setInvalidFields] = React.useState([]);


return (
<ComponentB
invalidInputs = {inavlidFields.length !== 0}
/>
)
```

Does component B rerender when the state invalidFields changes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does rerender

Props of this component change so it should rerender

Comment: So the comparison is evaluated again in the parent component? Note that the property is of type boolean.

Comment: `ComponentA` rerenders and all the code inside the function runs again

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will render, because when invalidFields changes it will also change the length and when the length changes useState -> calls the function setInvalidFields once this is set with newly changed field, it will re-execute the entire component and inavlidFields.length !== 0 becomes true and Component B Renders

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).